# Literal does not match format string error in oracle

Tags: oracle

I was given a SELECT statement that is running in a Crystal Report to investigate a data problem but when I try to run it against the database I get the error:

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
>   01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
>   *Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
>              the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
>              "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
>              with no extra whitespace.
>   *Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.

I think it has to do with the Date comparisons but I am not sure what is wrong. I know nothing about oracle and since the error message does not specify the line the error is on I am only guessing at what might be the problem. Can anyone point me to what is causing this problem?

```
   SELECT ACTDET.GROSS_VOLUME, 
          ACTDET.NET_VOLUME,
          ACTIVITY.SHIPPER_ID,
          ACTIVITY.ACTIVITY_START_DATE,
          SHIPPER.NAME_1,
          TANK.TANK_PRODUCT_CODE,
          PRODUCT.DESCRIPTION_2,
          SITE.NAME_1,
          SITE.NAME_2
   FROM   G3USER.ACTIVITY ACTIVITY,
          G3USER.ACTDET ACTDET,
          G3USER.SHIPPER SHIPPER,
          G3USER.TANK TANK,
          G3USER.SITE SITE,
          G3USER.PRODUCT PRODUCT
   WHERE ((ACTIVITY.TERMINAL_ID=ACTDET.TERMINAL_ID) AND (ACTIVITY.BOL_NUMBER=ACTDET.BOL_NUMBER))
   AND ((ACTIVITY.TERMINAL_ID=SHIPPER.TERMINAL_ID) AND (ACTIVITY.SHIPPER_ID=SHIPPER.SHIPPER_ID))
   AND ((ACTDET.TERMINAL_ID=TANK.TERMINAL_ID) AND (ACTDET.TANK_ID=TANK.TANK_ID))
   AND (ACTDET.TERMINAL_ID=SITE.TERMINAL_ID)
   AND ((TANK.TERMINAL_ID=PRODUCT.TERMINAL_ID AND (TANK.TANK_PRODUCT_CODE=PRODUCT.PRODUCT_CODE))
   AND (ACTIVITY.ACTIVITY_START_DATE >= '2014-02-05 00:00:00') AND (ACTIVITY.ACTIVITY_START_DATE < '2014-02-06 00:00:00'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle doesn't understand the literal date format strings, as they are not in the same format that your client is configured for. You need to use the `TO_DATE` function to tell Oracle the format of the date string you are presenting it with, like so:

```
AND (ACTIVITY.ACTIVITY_START_DATE >= TO_DATE('2014-02-05 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) 
AND (ACTIVITY.ACTIVITY_START_DATE < TO_DATE('2014-02-06 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')));
```

You could also represent your dates using ANSI syntax (seeing as they have no time component):

```
AND (ACTIVITY.ACTIVITY_START_DATE >= DATE'2014-02-05') 
AND (ACTIVITY.ACTIVITY_START_DATE < DATE'2014-02-06'));
```

Answer (score -1):

A default installation of Oracle Database sets the default DATE format to DD-MON-YYYY.

And you were using a different format in your  sql query. Either you can use to_date function or simply change the date format model to DD-MON-YYYY. .

[Click here to see the oracle reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jan/o12plsql-1408561.html)

Answer (score -2):

If `ACTIVITY.ACTIVITY_START_DATE` has the DATE data type, the comparison should look something like this (you cannot always compare dates with stings in the Oracle Database):

`...ACTIVITY.ACTIVITY_START_DATE >= TO_DATE('2014-02-05 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`